# How should I handle the problem "package contains empty filename" that stops me from installing the newest kernel update?

Tags: kernel, apt, software-installation, upgrade

I have just tried to install the newest kernel update and it fails at the package `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-109-generic` with the following output: (username and hostname are not the real ones ;)

```
user@laptop:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade -y
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd       
Läser tillståndsinformation… Färdig
Beräknar uppgradering… Färdig
Följande NYA paket kommer att installeras:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-120 linux-headers-5.4.0-120-generic linux-image-5.4.0-120-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-120-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-120-generic
Följande paket kommer att uppgraderas:
  apt apt-utils bluetooth bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd ca-certificates e2fsprogs ffmpeg firefox firefox-locale-de firefox-locale-en firefox-locale-sv intel-microcode libapt-pkg6.0 libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra58
  libavcodec-extra58:i386 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libavutil56:i386 libbluetooth3 libcom-err2 libcom-err2:i386 libext2fs2 liblouis-data liblouis20 libpostproc55 libss2 libswresample3
  libswresample3:i386 libswscale5 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev logsave python3-louis
41 att uppgradera, 5 att nyinstallera, 0 att ta bort och 0 att inte uppgradera.
33 standard security updates
Behöver hämta 0 B/167 MB arkiv.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer ytterligare 382 MB utrymme användas på disken.
Plockar ut mallar från paketen: 100%
Förkonfigurerar paket ...
dpkg: ej återhämtningsbart allvarligt fel, avbryter:
 fillistfilen för paketet "linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-109-generic" innehåller tomt filnamn
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
user@laptop:~$
```

For those of you who don't understand the Swedish output from above, here's the same output, roughly translated by me:

```
user@laptop:~$ sudo apt full-upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Complete
Building dependency tree       
Reading package states… Complete
Calculating upgrade… Complete
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-120 linux-headers-5.4.0-120-generic linux-image-5.4.0-120-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-120-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-120-generic
The following packages will be updated:
  apt apt-utils bluetooth bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd ca-certificates e2fsprogs ffmpeg firefox firefox-locale-de firefox-locale-en firefox-locale-sv intel-microcode libapt-pkg6.0 libavcodec-extra libavcodec-extra58
  libavcodec-extra58:i386 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libavutil56:i386 libbluetooth3 libcom-err2 libcom-err2:i386 libext2fs2 liblouis-data liblouis20 libpostproc55 libss2 libswresample3
  libswresample3:i386 libswscale5 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev logsave python3-louis
41 to update, 5 to newly install, 0 to uninstall and 0 to upgrade.
33 standard security updates
Need to download 0 B/167 MB of archives.
After this action additional 382 MB of disk space will be used.
Choosing templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring package ...
dpkg: unrecoverable error, cancelling:
 the file list file for "linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-109-generic" contains empty file name
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
user@laptop:~$
```

`sudo apt upgrade -y` gives the exact same output. Yes, I ran `sudo apt update` seconds before and tried to upgrade several times, while clearing the cache after each try.
And I want to get the updates done because nothing else updates in this process ant it would be too tedious to update each package seperately. Plus I want to have the newest kernel which is impossible when the necessary package fails to install. Can I repair the package manually by opening it, searching for the damaged file and fixing the issue (probably a syntax-related issue...)? Or should I just wait for the next update?

Comment: Send the error text to the package maintainer and wait for a correct one?

Comment: You should also probably specify exactly which version of what Linux distribution you are running. A lot of them are apt based.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Every package operation failed because of the error shown in the question. And I found out what the problem is:
I accidentally booted a qemu VM from /dev/sda (which is my boot drive) and so the secondly started instance of Linux Mint did the startup routine and when I shut it down again it did the shutdown routine. That messed up the file list for the package for which the error showed up. And when I opened it with xed it contained lots of invalid characters and some text that seemed to be ripped-apart log messages. There was nothing even closely resembling a file path and the file was ~35MB in size (which isn't a size I would expect from a file list!).

I then found out that deleting the damaged list and reinstalling the package helps - it did!